# eCommerce on IPhone & Android, do we have to pay a % to apple & google for each transaction?

Tags: android, iphone, e-commerce

We are taking a decision to build a native ecommerce app for iphone and android platforms, do we have to pay apple or google a % for each transaction that happens on the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple and google charge 30% of the amount as transaction fee for all the transaction happen over their servers.

If you want to build a e-commerce app , then I will suggest you to use a third party payment gateway like paypal